# React Form won't save date

Tags: html, sql, reactjs, forms, date

I've created a basic form in React to save a name, category, and date if available to an SQL table.  My form is acting fine - it's submitting correctly and saving the new entries.  The problem is, while it saves the name and the category fine, if you choose a date (using the HTML date picker) the date isn't getting saved.  It's definitely seeing the date in the state upon change, but it won't save to the SQL table. Instead it's saving the state as "null."

When I use Terminal to add an item, I'm able to set the date when using an INSERT command, and it will save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code it's quite difficult to debug. It could be the format of the date value you're using, can you `console.log` the date before you send it off the SQL server?

Additionally, depending on how you're interacting with the SQL server you could open up the dev tools and go to the Network tab and see what's in the HTTP POST request?

Comment: You're right of course!  Sorry, I'm a bit rusty with my Stack Overflow asking!  I did a console log of the date, and this is what it returned:  <input type="date" id="date" value="2021-06-15">   I also looked at the Network tab, and it seems like the POST request is going through fine - it's definitely working.  The only thing it's doing is instead of saving that date value, it's saving null.

Comment: This sounds like you're passing through the `input` element itself instead of the input's value. It may be easier if you could post the code of how you're capturing the input in the question because I'm guessing you need to do something like `value.currentTarget.value` (or whatever the input event object is)

Comment: Here's the line that grabs the date - it uses a hook.  <input type="date" id="date" value={date} onChange={e => setDate(e.target.value)}/>

Comment: This looks correct, and when you `console.log(date);` you get `<input type="date" id="date" value="2021-06-15">`? This may be quicker if you posted your component code in the question or even use a code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/) because I can't determine how you're passing the value through to your API POST request

Comment: Well now suddenly I got it to work!  So who knows.  But thank you for your help!